# How to add Label to a PGF plot that uses hardcoded table data

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've tried several methods and all of them return errors.

How can I add a label for these plot lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textheight,
    xlabel=Número de operações de busca,
    ylabel=Tempo (em segundos)
  ] 
    %\addplot gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)}; 
    \addplot[mark=none,  green] table[
    x=quantidade, y=tempo,
    /pgf/number format/read comma as period% <---
    ] {
    quantidade  tempo
    100 0.012
    10000   0.941
    100000   8.887
    1000000  88.845

    };
 \addplot[mark=none,  black] table[
    x=quantidade, y=tempo,
    /pgf/number format/read comma as period% <---
    ] {
    quantidade  tempo
    100 0.002
    10000   0.169
    100000   1.661
    1000000  16.572

    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Gráfico que apresenta o crescimento do tempo de caminhamento pelo número de entradas de uma Tabela.}
\label{caminhamento}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, but `\usepackage{pgfplots}` is missing. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "label", exactly? Do you mean a legend?

Comment: I mean a text following the trace

Answer (score 2):

To add a text parallel to the plot, add `node [sloped,above,<position>] {..}` between the coordinate list and the semicolon of the `\addplot`. `<position>` can be e.g. `midway` or `near end`, or a fraction such as `pos=0.25`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textheight,
    xlabel=Número de operações de busca,
    ylabel=Tempo (em segundos),
    legend pos=north west
  ] 
    %\addplot gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)}; 
    \addplot[mark=none,  green] table[
    x=quantidade, y=tempo,
    /pgf/number format/read comma as period% <---
    ] {
    quantidade  tempo
    100 0.012
    10000   0.941
    100000   8.887
    1000000  88.845
    }
    node[midway,sloped,above] {Lorem ipsum};
 \addplot[mark=none,  black] table[
    x=quantidade, y=tempo,
    /pgf/number format/read comma as period% <---
    ] {
    quantidade  tempo
    100 0.002
    10000   0.169
    100000   1.661
    1000000  16.572
    }
    node[near end,sloped,above] {Put something here};

\addlegendentry{First plot}
\addlegendentry{Second plot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Gráfico que apresenta o crescimento do tempo de caminhamento pelo número de entradas de uma Tabela.}
\label{caminhamento}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was how I interpreted "following the trace", if you meant something else, please try clarifying your question.